# Fetch the value of axios base url in a vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I have setup my axios configuration in vuejs global configuration like this

```
const axiosConfig = {
baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
timeout: 30000, 
 };
Vue.prototype.$axios =  axios.create(axiosConfig);
```

Now i would like to retrieve the value of basEuRL Inside a component

```
<script>
  data:()=>({
     apiurl:this.$axios.baseURL
   })
<script>
```

But the above doesnt work. I expected the property apiurl to have

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
```

Comment: `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'`  in main.js with single file component setup.  Then just use `/something` elsewhere to get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/something`. https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you need call the baseURL in a data component, but I found a common way to use axios baseURL like this [Vue.js REST API Consumption with Axios](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/):

```
// http-common.js
import axios from 'axios';

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer {token}'
  }
})
```

Then

```
import {HTTP} from './http-common';
HTTP.get(`posts`)
    .then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
```